# how to use where clause in join usinq linq for the following T-SQL query?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

how to use where clause in join usinq linq for the following T-SQL query?

```
select * from 
tbl1 inner join tbl2 
on tbl1.id = tbl2.id
where tdl1.col = tbl2.col
```

Answer (score 0):

After writing a lot of linq queries I finally found the answer...

```
from t1 in tbl1
from t2 in tbl2
where t1.id == t2.id && t1.col1 == t2.col2
select new {
               Anything...
           }
```